# Flutter Navigator 2 Prevent Forward Navigation on Web

Tags: flutter

After navigating to a new Route using Flutter's Navigator 2 and then navigating back, the forward button in the browser is enabled.

Pressing the forward button navigates to the popped route.

How can the forward page entry be removed from the browser's navigation stack? After navigating back, the user should no longer be able to navigate forward.